# Appending subprocess output to file from Python script

Tags: python, popen, system-calls, output-redirect

I have a python script which loops through some data and calls a subprocess each time, passing the data in as part of the process's arguments. I want to append the output of each call to a file so I can use that output later in the script.

I have tried using os.system and putting ">> outfile.txt" after the command. However, in this case for some reason the first iterations are output to the shell as normal and only the final iteration is appended to the file.

```
def runSpecificList( streamList ):
    for line in open( streamList, 'r' ):
        getSpecificStream( 'list.txt', line )


def getSpecificStream( testList, id ):
    os.system( os.environ['path'] + r'\sub\path\to\program.exe argument' + id + ' >> ' + list )
```

I found that this could possibly be achieved using subprocess.popen(), so I tried that... however, this time the first iteration was written to file, and the rest of the time what was written to file seemed to be random fragments. And, also, I was unable to properly use the file later in the script for some reason.

```
def getSpecificStream( testList, id ):
     log = open( testList, 'a' )
     subproc.Popen([os.environ['path'] + r'\sub\path\to\program.exe', 'argument' + id], stdout = log, stderr = log, shell = True )
```

Anybody have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your processes are not synchronized, so they print the output in a random order (based on the order of the execution).

You could use a `Queue` to return the output to the master process (the one that spawn the others) and then manipulate it.

See: http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes

Comment: As far as I can tell, that would require me to modify the behaviour of the program I am calling. That's not something I can do.